# Serializing/deserializing with BinaryFormatter when class has implicit operator

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion, binaryformatter

We are using BinaryFormatter to convert objects to bytes when transferring between a server and client.

All classes that we need to transfer uses the `[Serializable]` attribute, and it normally works as it should. We also use our own SerializationBinder when deserializing, to map it to the correct object type and assembly.

But we have a problem when serializing/deserializing any object that has an implicit operator.
When deserializing it does this from the operator type and value, and thus potentially loose information.
So for instance, a class with two properties and one implicit operator, it will try to deserialize the object from the implicit operator type, and the values from the two properties seems lost.

How can I force it to behave normally just like any other class? Or am I missing something?

## Update

When doing further investigation, it seems like a combination of a wrapper class implementing ISerializable and child property using an implicit operator returning certain types.

example:

```
[Serializable]
    class Dto
    {
        public int MyNumber { get; set; }

        // The implicit operator returning an int will be used when deseralized instead of the complete object
        // If you change it to the operator returning a string, it will not be used at all.
        // Other types like decimal will also trigger the problem, and if multiple are present the int seems to be one that is used.

        public static implicit operator int(Dto dto) => dto.MyNumber;
        //public static implicit operator string(Dto dto) => dto.MyNumber.ToString();
        //public static implicit operator decimal(Dto dto) => (decimal)dto.MyNumber;
    }

    [Serializable]
    class DtoWrapper : ISerializable
    {
        public Dto Dto { get; set; }

        public DtoWrapper() { }

        public DtoWrapper(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            Dto = (Dto)info.GetValue(nameof(Dto), typeof(Dto));
        }

        public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            info.AddValue(nameof(Dto), Dto);
        }
    }
```

When first serializing and then deserializing an instance of the `DtoWrapper` class, there will be an error that the Dto property cannot be set from an integer.

Comment: To change the type during serialization and deserialization very explicit steps are needed, operators are not enough. During serialization the `SerializationInfo.SetType()` can change the type, on deserialization the `IObjectReference` implementation can return another type and of course a custom binder can map to any type by the stored assembly and type name. My bet in on the latter one but without providing a reproducible example I cannot be sure.

Comment: I love getting -1 without any comment on what was disliked.

Comment: @taffer The problem isn't that I want to change type. It is done automatically by the BinaryFormatter even though I don't want it to. If I remove the implicit operator method from the class everything works fine.

Comment: That's why I said a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be required. Until then we can try convince each other whether this can or cannot be due to the operators but it has no point. In the binder you can check the stored type though so you can see whether the deserialization is okay at the point you need to map the type.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem was to use the overload method for AddValue() where the type is explicitly set, like this:

```
info.AddValue(nameof(Dto), Dto, typeof(Dto));
```

This solved the issue.